# Assign default argument value the caller's argument value

Tags: ruby, methods, arguments, default

How can I assign the value of the caller's argument as a default value of an argument?
I want the method `Callme#callme` to have as the default argument value the value of the `name` argument of the caller method `TheCaller#caller`.

```
module Callme
  def callme(hero = name)
    hero
  end
end

class TheCaller
  include Callme 
  def caller(name)
    callme
  end
end

say = TheCaller.new
say.caller("superman")
# => expecting "superman"
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no implicit way of doing this that I'm aware of.  Your best bet is to just pass the args through

```
class TheCaller
  include Callme
  def caller(*args)
    callme(*args)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understand the question, but adding a name accessor to TheCaller seems to make this work as expected:

```
module Callme
  def callme(hero = name)
    hero
  end
end

class TheCaller
  attr_accessor :name
  include Callme 
  def caller(name)
    @name = name
    callme
  end
end

say = TheCaller.new
p say.caller("superman")

# => "superman"
```

Comment: Yup! Including this module will lend its 'callme' method to 'TheCaller' class as if it were its own instance method. Hence, 'callme' method will be able to access the instance variable '@name' natively.